# How to make my script actually execute, rathern than just print to console?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to make the following snippet execute automatically. I have enabled permissions. I'm new to both Linux and shell scripting, and know very little about it. 
Here is the code I would like to execute:

```
raspivid  -t -0 -w 1080 -h 720 -awb auto -fps 30 -rot 90 -b 1200000 
-o -|ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i - -vcodec copy -an -f flv 
-metadata streamName=myStream tcp://0.0.0.0:6666&
```

It works fine when I paste it into the command line and press "enter". However, I need it to execute automatically, so I'm trying to write a script to do that.
This is what I've tried to do in nano editor:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "...above code here..."
```

This only prints to console (probably obvious), but how can I make it execute?
1. I have made it executable (I believe) by using

```
sudo chmod +x start2s.sh
```

I have also enabled permissions like this:

```
sudo chmod 755 start2s.sh
```

When I type

```
sh start2s.sh
```

it just prints to console. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just paste the command into the file. `echo "..."` prints the text in between quotes to the console. And you can run the script like `./start2s.sh`, you don't need `sh` there.

Comment: Good point, thank you. It makes sense, but I'm still having issues - it runs, but with errors (see my comment @ Ljm Dullaart). It runs fine if I just type it into the command line and hit Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic scripting tips:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'ls'
```

will print

```
ls
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
ls
```

will give you the output of `ls`.

In general, you will put an echo in your script

- if you have something to output from the script
- during development: if you want to be sure  the command and arguments are correct, for example, because the command destroys things.

In the latter case, you will remove the echo from the script once you have verified the corretness.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - makes sense! Unfortunately, however, it behaves differently than if I simply enter it at the command line and hit Enter (in this case, it works properly). If I simply paste the command after the she-bang line, I get the following error messages:     mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates